# How to create maintenance plan in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, maintenance-plan

When I'm trying to create a new maintenance plan in SQL Server, it is showing this error:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

'Agent XPs' component is turned off as part of the security configuration for 
this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Agent XPs' by using   sp_configure. 
For more information about enabling 'Agent XPs', see "Surface Area   Configuration" in 
SQL Server Books Online. (ObjectExplorer)
```

Comment: You will also get this message if the SQL Server Agent service is not running. In addition to the T-SQL answers, check the Windows services list for SQL Server Agent, and make sure it is set to start automatically and running.

Answer (score 53):

You need to enable the SQL Server Agent extended stored procedures first by running the following.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Agent XPs', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```